# Connected, but no internet after new ISP on 21.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, dns

Recently moved and now have Spectrum instead of AT&T.

2 machines on the network.  Windows box works fine.

Ubuntu machine connects fine to local network, but intermittent internet.  (long load times, times out most of the time).

apt-get update never works

Things I've tried:

- deleting and resetting up the connection
- setting DNS to 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
- installing resolveconf
- purging avahi
- changing ethernet cables
- plugging directly into modem instead of linksys router

Nothing is working or making any effect.

I have not changed anything on the system except plugging it in at a new location.

specs:

- ubuntu 21.04

```
nmcli
enp3s0: connected to Profile 1
        "Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x"
        ethernet (alx), 44:8A:5B:9C:2A:A9, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default
        inet4 192.168.1.101/24
        route4 0.0.0.0/0
        route4 169.254.0.0/16
        route4 192.168.1.0/24
...
DNS configuration:
        servers: 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        interface: enp3s0

cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
nameserver 8.8.8.8

systemd-resolve --status
Global
           Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
    resolv.conf mode: foreign
  Current DNS Server: 9.9.9.9
         DNS Servers: 9.9.9.9 2620:fe::fe
Fallback DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8 2001:4860:4860::8888

Link 2 (enp3s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 8.8.4.4
       DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

debug commands

```
nslookup -debug security.ubuntu.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: Did the new ISP not send you a new modem/router?

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: this is an ability to reach DNS servers issue, not a "connected to network" issue.  as I said above, the windows box works as well as wifi for phones, etc.  journalctl has nothing of interest as it is just logging the network is connected.  it doesn't log DNS errors.

Comment: I seem to have the same issue with new ISP. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @user87317 I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu and it worked perfectly after.  Which points to some Ubuntu configuration issue.  I never found a command to refresh it.  I might try a livecd see if it makes a difference for you